# Having a 3D point projected onto a 3D plane, find the 2D coord based on the plane two axis

Tags: three.js

I have a `THREE.Plane` `plane` which is intersected by a number of `THREE.Line3` `lines[]`.

Using only this information, how can I acquire a 2D coordinate set of points?

Edit for better understanding the problem:

The 2D coordinate is related to the plane, so imagine the 3D plane becomes a Cartesian plane drawn on a blackboard. It is pretty much a 3D drawing of a 2D plane. What I want to find is the X, Y values of points previously projected onto this Cartesian plane. But they are 3D, just like the 3D plane.

Comment: Are you looking for [Plane.projectPoint()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Plane.projectPoint)? This method projects a point in 3D space onto the defined plane.

Comment: I read about this method, but I don't understand how the output, a `Vector3` would help me.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not clear what you mean with "2D coordinate set of points". Since `THREE.Plane` is defined in 3D space, a projected on the plane is also a 3D coordinate.

Comment: Edited for better understanding.

Comment: You need more information, namely the direction of _one_ of the primary axes (`X` or `Y`) relative to your plane (i.e. which way your plane represents "up"). Without those, you don't know how your plane is oriented (because a `Plane` is an infinite planar space), so the best you can do is get the line intersection distance from the origin. If you know one of your axes, please include that information in your question.

Comment: I know the plane's normal and constant "d". Beside that, I know the point that is coplanar to it (the projected 3d point).

Comment: I can request 3 coplanar points used to build the plane, but I'd prefer to only use the information I already have. If possible, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have enough information. In this answer I'll explain why, and provide more information to achieve what you want, should you be able to provide the necessary information

First, let's create a plane. Like you, I'm uing [`Plane.setFromNormalAndCoplanarPoint`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Plane.setFromNormalAndCoplanarPoint). I'm considering the co-planar point as the origin (`(0, 0)`) of the plane's Cartesian space.

```
let normal = new Vector3(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random()).normalize()
let origin = new Vector3(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random()).normalize().setLength(10)
let plane = new Plane.setFromNormalAndCoplanarPoint(normal, origin)
```

Now, we create a random 3D point, and project it onto the plane.

```
let point1 = new Vector3(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random()).normalize()
let projectedPoint1 = new Vector3()
plane.projectPoint(point1, projectedPoint1)
```

The `projectedPoint1` variable is now co-planar with your plane. But this plane is infinite, with no discrete `X`/`Y` axes. So currently we can only get the distance from the origin to the projected point.

```
let distance = origin.distanceTo(projectedPoint1)
```

In order to turn this into a Cartesian coordinate, you need to define at least one axis. To make this truly random, let's compute a random `+Y` axis:

```
let tempY = new Vector3(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random())
let pY = new Vector3()
plane.projectPoint(tempY, pY)
pY.normalize()
```

Now that we have `+Y`, let's get `+X`:

```
let pX = new Vector3().crossVectors(pY, normal)
pX.normalize()
```

Now, we can project the plane-projected point onto the axis vectors to get the Cartesian coordinates.

```
let x = projectedPoint1.clone().projectOnVector(pX).distanceTo(origin)
if(!projectedPoint1.clone().projectOnVector(pX).normalize().equals(pX)){
  x = -x
}

let y = projectedPoint1.clone().projectOnVector(pY).distanceTo(origin)
if(!projectedPoint1.clone().projectOnVector(pY).normalize().equals(pY)){
  y = -y
}
```

Note that in order to get negative values, I check a normalized copy of the axis-projected vector against the normalized axis vector. If they match, the value is positive. If they don't match, the value is negative.

Also, all the `clone`-ing I did above was to be explicit with the steps. This is not an efficient way to perform this operation, but I'll leave optimization up to you.

**EDIT:** My logic for determining the sign of the value was flawed. I've corrected the logic to normalize the projected point and check against the normalized axis vector.

Comment: After reading both your comment and answer I figured there was a way to find the Y axis of the plane based on the camera position in my code. Something "I didn't know I needed to know". That way I was able to build the Cartesian X and Y axes. The last piece of code, though, is the one I was really needing help with. Thanks.

Comment: @AlexandreSeverino I had to correct some logic in the last piece of code. It worked because everything was normalized. Now it will work regardless of how large your values are.

Comment: Are you sure your last code block works now? I copied it exactly and get the following results: https://imgur.com/AR7q6b4

The sphere in the center is the origin. The red line accounts for the X axis. The green one is Y. (Normal / Z is behind the sphere).

On the right canvas, the result of the projection to 2D.

Comment: Got this working. It's important to give a tolerance when checking equality between the normalized projection and the axis. In other words, "equals" is too restrictive.

Comment: @AlexandreSeverino Yes, you've found one of the follies of JavaScript. I usually use a tolerance of `1e-6`, based purely on my observations of accuracy across engines.